# Peculiar enum in c++

Tags: c++, struct, enums, initialization

In a library I have come across a weird construction which serves as enum:

```
typedef struct SetControl
{
  const static uint16_t RC_MODE_ERROR;
  const static uint16_t RELEASE_CONTROL_SUCCESS;
  const static uint16_t OBTAIN_CONTROL_SUCCESS;
  const static uint16_t OBTAIN_CONTROL_IN_PROGRESS;
  const static uint16_t RELEASE_CONTROL_IN_PROGRESS;
  const static uint16_t RC_NEED_MODE_F;
  const static uint16_t RC_NEED_MODE_P;
  const static uint16_t IOC_OBTAIN_CONTROL_ERROR;
} SetControl;
```

The members are not initialized anywhere but even though, `RC_MODE_ERROR` equals 0, `RELEASE_CONTROL_SUCCESS` equals 1 and so on. I know because I have logged it with printf. I haven't seen anything like it so far. Why does it even work (I thought values will be initialized by random data by default, or 0)? Is there any add value from this over standard `enum`?

What can I try next?

Comment: @EdChum but this is not declared as an enum.  These are members of a struct

Comment: Those values _have to_ be defined somewhere, somehow. Keep digging!

Comment: They look like macros they are probably macro defined somewhere, is there some `#define ...` somewhere

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a cpp file that doesn't set these static members?  What you are seeing should not happen unless it is coded to do so.

Comment: @EdChum how exactly do they _look like macro_? Is it because they are all uppercase?

Comment: I agree with what @EdChum said. Normally, those members would be [initialized to 0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6032696/7571171)

Comment: @EdChum it's OK, I think we all do that sometimes

Comment: @YSC yes, it's not required but it's a convention I've seen and used

Comment: @EdChum it is conventional to name macro identifiers with all caps, but all caps identifiers are not necessarily macros ;) I see nothing that hints to a macro definition here.

Comment: @YSC true but this isn't exactly an MVCE anyway, looking at it I suspect these are macro defined

Comment: @YSC OK they're not macros but scoped consts

Comment: @EdChum This is a possible explanation, but you wrote _"They look like macros they are probably macro"_ and I disagree with that. This is not _"probably macro"_, it _might_ be macros.

Comment: The code base where you found it predates C++11, most probably. This is a poor-man's scoped enumeration with an underlying type. Nowadays we'd opt to write it as `enum class SetControl : std::uint16_t { ... };`. Also that `typedef` is completely superfluous.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To begin with, this is *not* an enum, this is a struct. These are [different concepts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20681224/2411320), but I think you knew, just got confused by the usage here.

It is *not* expected for the members of a struct to be assigned to these values (as for example would happen with an [enum](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum)).

I am fairly sure that these members get initialized somewhere in your code, or they are Macros, thus are defined somewhere.

---

After searching [Github](https://github.com/dji-sdk/Onboard-SDK/blob/3.3/osdk-core/api/inc/dji_error.hpp#L295), they are initialized, like this:

```
const uint16_t DJI::OSDK::ErrorCode::ControlACK::SetControl::RC_MODE_ERROR = 0x0000;
const uint16_t DJI::OSDK::ErrorCode::ControlACK::SetControl::RELEASE_CONTROL_SUCCESS = 0x0001;
const uint16_t DJI::OSDK::ErrorCode::ControlACK::SetControl::OBTAIN_CONTROL_SUCCESS = 0x0002;
const uint16_t DJI::OSDK::ErrorCode::ControlACK::SetControl::OBTAIN_CONTROL_IN_PROGRESS = 0x0003;
const uint16_t DJI::OSDK::ErrorCode::ControlACK::SetControl::RELEASE_CONTROL_IN_PROGRESS = 0x0004;
const uint16_t DJI::OSDK::ErrorCode::ControlACK::SetControl::RC_NEED_MODE_F = 0x0006;
const uint16_t DJI::OSDK::ErrorCode::ControlACK::SetControl::RC_NEED_MODE_P = 0x0005;
const uint16_t DJI::OSDK::ErrorCode::ControlACK::SetControl::IOC_OBTAIN_CONTROL_ERROR = 0x00C9;
```

in [dji_error.cpp](https://github.com/dji-sdk/Onboard-SDK/blob/b2f28f8702efcdd3599ea618c2d472f3e9f90d01/osdk-core/api/src/dji_error.cpp).

Comment: I cant find that anywhere, take a look: https://github.com/dji-sdk/Onboard-SDK/blob/3.3/osdk-core/api/inc/dji_error.hpp#L295

Comment: @Bremen You need to look [here](https://github.com/dji-sdk/Onboard-SDK/blob/3.3/osdk-core/api/src/dji_error.cpp)

Comment: @NathanOliver and Basya  I was 30 secs faster =)

Comment: @gsamaras: you are fast.  beat me to it!

Answer (score -1):

Static members needs to be separately defined.

Ex:

```
// in example.h
struct SetControl
{
    const static uint16_t RC_MODE_ERROR; // this is only a declaration
};

// in example.cpp
const uint16_t SetControl::RC_MODE_ERROR = 1; // this is the definition
```

Comment: That's not true for const integer.

Comment: yes it is, for a `const static` **without initializer**